# Formula for Fibonacci sequence modulo 11

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

Consider the following question from Weissman [1]

> Prove that for $n \ge 1$, $F_n \equiv 4^{n-1} (2^{n} - 1) \mod 11$ for the Fibonacci sequence $F_0 = 0$, $F_1 = 1$, $F_2 = 1$, $F_3 = 2$, $\ldots$

We can use induction for this and I've posted a proof below. It seems a bit lengthy and needs a couple of side results on recurrence relations for powers of 2 and 4 mod 11. I would like to ask if anyone knows of a 'cleaner' or simpler proof.

---

Proof using induction:
The formula is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$. If we
assume the relation $F_n \equiv 4^{n-1} (2^{n} - 1) \mod 11$ holds for $n \le k$.

Now use
$F_{k+1} = F_{k} + F_{k-1}$ so that $F_{k+1} \equiv F_{k} + F_{k-1} \mod 11$.

Using the induction hypothesis, 
$$
F_{k+1} \equiv 
4^{k-1} (2^{k} - 1) 
+
4^{k-2} (2^{k-1} - 1) 
\mod 11
$$
so that
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_{k+1} 
&\equiv 
4^{k-2} 
\left(
4 (2^{k} - 1) 
+
(2^{k-1} - 1) 
\right)
\mod 11
\\
&\equiv 
4^{k-2} 
\left(
4 \cdot 2^{k} - 4 
+
2^{k-1} - 1
\right)
\mod 11
\\
&\equiv 
4^{k-2} 
\left(
2^{k+2}  
+
2^{k-1} - 5
\right)
\mod 11
\end{aligned}
$$

Inside the bracket above, we can use the relation 
(see separate proof):
$$
2^{k-1} + 2^{k} + 2^{k+2} \equiv 0 \mod 11 
\quad \text{ which gives } \quad
2^{k-1} +  2^{k+2} \equiv - 2^{k} \mod 11 
$$

Substituting into the earlier expression gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_{k+1} 
&\equiv 
4^{k-2} 
\left(
- 2^{k}  - 5
\right)
\mod 11
\\ &\equiv 
4^{k-2} 
\left(
10 \cdot 2^{k}  - 5
\right)
\mod 11
\\ &\equiv 
5 \cdot 4^{k-2} 
\left(
2^{k+1}  - 1
\right)
\mod 11
\end{aligned}
$$

Now use the relation $5 \cdot 4^{k-2} \equiv 4^{k} \mod 11$ (see separate proof) to obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
F_{k+1} 
&\equiv 
4^{k} 
\left(
2^{k+1}  - 1
\right)
\mod 11
\end{aligned}
$$
which shows that the formula holds for $n=k+1$ and completes the proof by induction.

---

Proof of $2^{k-1} + 2^{k} + 2^{k+2} \equiv 0 \mod 11 $:

$$
\begin{aligned}
2^{k-1} + 2^{k} + 2^{k+1} 
& \equiv 
2^{k-1} (1 + 2 + 4) \mod 11
\\
& \equiv 
2^{k-1} \cdot 7 \mod 11
\\
& \equiv 
2^{k-1} \cdot (-4) \equiv - 2^{k+1}\mod 11
\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Which gives 
$$
2^{k-1} + 2^{k} + 2 \cdot 2^{k+1} \equiv 0 \mod 11
\quad \text{ i.e. }
2^{k-1} + 2^{k} + 2^{k+2} \equiv 0 \mod 11
$$

---

Proof of $5 \cdot 4^{k-2} \equiv 4^{k} \mod 11$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
5 \cdot 4^{k-2} 
& \equiv
- 6 \cdot 4^{k-2} \mod 11
\\
&\equiv
- 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 4^{k-2} \mod 11
\\
&\equiv
8 \cdot 2 \cdot 4^{k-2} \mod 11
\\
&\equiv
16 \cdot 4^{k-2} \mod 11
\\
&\equiv
4^{k} \mod 11
\end{aligned}
$$

---

[1]: Weissman, Illustrated Theory of Numbers (AMS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is another take.

Recall [Binet's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression) for the Fibonacci numbers:
$$
F_n = \frac{\varphi^n-\psi^n}{\varphi-\psi}
$$
where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are the roots $x^2-x-1$.

The same formula holds mod $11$ because $x^2-x-1$ does have two roots mod $11$. They are $\varphi=8$ and $\psi=4$. Therefore,
$$
F_n = \frac{8^n-4^n}{8-4} = \frac{8^n-4^n}{4} = 2^{3n-2}-4^{n-1} = 4^{n-1} (2^{n} - 1) \bmod 11
$$

Comment: Also, $F_n \equiv 3(8^n-4^n) \bmod 11$, which looks much nicer.

Comment: Thanks for this. The conclusion is neat. I struggle though on how to go from Binet, a formula for $F_n$ using powers of irrationals, to the world of modular arithmetic. Yes, the same quadratic has roots mod 11, but how does this lead to a Binet-like formula in mod 11? Apologies if I'm missing something obvious ...

Comment: @PaulAljabar,  it boils down to this: the sequences $8^n$ and $4^n$ are linearly independent solutions of the Fibonacci recurrence in $\mathbb F_{11}$ and so all solutions are linear combinations of them. Binet's formula in $\mathbb R$ comes from this reasoning, for different sequences, of course.

Comment: Okay, I think I see now. I guess the key is that if we want to solve  any sequence that has the Fibonacci property $F_n + F_{n+1} = F_{n+2}$ with a form $F_{n} = x^{n}$, then the relation translates to $x^{n} + x^{n+1} = x^{n+2}$ so that either $x=0$  or $1 + x = x^{2}$. So, in the non-trivial case, we are looking for solutions of $x^{2} - x - 1 = 0$ _regardless_ of the field we are working in, right?

Comment: For the Fibonacci sequence mod 11, we have $x = 8,4$ as solutions of the quadratic $x^{2} - x - 1 = 0$. Therefore $F_{n}$ mod 11 will  be a linear combination of $8^{n}$ and $4^{n}$. With $F_{n} \equiv  8^{n}a +  4^{n}b$ we need to solve for $a$, $b$. $F_{0} \equiv 0$ gives  $a + b \equiv 0$ and $F_{1} \equiv 1$ gives $8a + 4b \equiv 1 \mod 11$. One possibility for these is $a \equiv 3 $ and  $b \equiv -3 \mod 11$ to give $F_{n} \equiv 3 (8^{n} - 4^{n}) \mod 11$.

Comment: Nice, I guess, because we can extend to modulo other numbers (where the quadratic is solvable).

Comment: @PaulAljabar, it seems you've got it.

Comment: Ended up here following a "related" link from elsewhere. Thought that hmm, $5$ is a quadratic residue, so there is something simple ... sure enough :-)